# Uso del módulo de python os para indicar directorios de trabajo

Tags: python, jupyter, modulos

Resulta que estoy siguiendo un tutorial del uso de un módulo de python llamado SeqBreed que pueden encontrar [aquí](https://github.com/miguelperezenciso/SeqBreed/blob/master/SeqBreed_tutorial.ipynb). Siguiendo ese tutorial, lo que hago es importar los módulos que necesito así:

```
import sys
import os
from SeqBreed import genome as gg
from SeqBreed.selection import selection as sel
```

Luego usando el módulo `os`, indico la ubicación de la carpeta donde estan los datos, así:

```
ddir = os.getcwd() + '/test'
```

Por último, especifico solo uno de los archivos (llamado vcf_IND.vcf) que están dentro de la carpeta test, así:

```
vcffile = ddir+'/vcf_IND.vcf'
```

Al seguir estos pasos si es posible obtener un resultado. Sin embargo cuando trabajo en la forma en como yo tengo mis datos guardados, sale un mensaje que indica que mi directorio de trabajo no existe. Creo yo porque estoy trabajando mi proyecto con varias carpetas, mientras que en el tutorial la estructura de estas carpetas es distinta. Por ejemplo, mientras que en el tutorial el notebook de jupyter se encuentra fuera y los datos (vcf_IND.vcf) se encuentran dentro de la carpeta test, algo como esto:

```
├── jupyter_notebook
│    ├── test
          ├── vcf_IND.vcf
```

En mi caso, el jupyter notebook lo tengo dentro de una carpeta llamado codigo, mientras que los datos los tengo dentro de varias carpetas. Por ejemplo:

```
├── Codigo
│    ├── jupyter notebook
│        
├── Datos
│    ├── Datos_IND
│         ├── SeqBreed
│               ├── Plink
│                    ├── vcf_IND.vcf
```

¿Sería posible me puedan ayudar? Les agradecería cualquier ayudada brindada.

Comment: El módulo Path que está disponible en la librería estándar desde Python3.4 puede servir para ir hacia arriba en el sistema de archivos.

Comment: Sería de mucha ayuda si pudieras poner el mensaje de error concreto que te da. Por otro lado, tal como dice @LeonardoMartinez, también te recomiendo que uses el módulo `pathlib` para manejarte entre ficheros y directorios.

Comment: @ChemaCortes, este sería el mensaje de error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'home/leo/Escritorio/github/Repo_TFM/Datos/Datos_IND/SeqBreed/plink/vcf_IND.vcf'

Comment: Sin embargo se puede ver al usar ```os.path.exists('/home/leo/Escritorio/github/Repo_TFM/Datos/Datos_IND/SeqBreed/plink')``` que ese directorio si existe: ```True```.

Comment: Asegúrate que la ruta es correcta. En el error falta el primer `/` de la ruta del fichero.